# Magento :Write form data to csv file

Tags: magento-1.9, forms, csv

I want to write data in a form to a csv file. I have used the following code:

```
$data = array();
$data['name'] = $this->getRequest()->getParam('name');
$data['company'] = $this->getRequest()->getParam('company');
$data['email'] = $this->getRequest()->getParam('email');
$data_row[] = $data;

$fileName = "example.csv";

$var_csv = new Varien_File_Csv();

$var_csv->saveData($fileName, $data_row);
```

But it is not working. Where will be the location of the csv file. Please help.

Comment: whats your `$fileName` ?

Comment: $fileName is the csv file to where I want to write the data

Comment: yes give full path of your filepath in and in `$filename` it will be saved there

Comment: I want to save this csv file to my root directory. So what do I need to do?

Comment: I have added an answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set Dir path

```
$path = Mage::getBaseDir('var') . DS . 'export' . DS;
$name = 'yourFileName';
$file = $path . DS . $name . '.csv';
```

and save it

```
$var_csv->saveData($file, $data_row);
```

so it will be saved in `<your magento>/var/export/yourFileName.csv`

**EDIT**

If you want to save it in your magento root dir

```
$path = Mage::getBaseDir();
```

Comment: Thank you.It worked.One more question ,how can I append the data to the existing csv on submitting the form each time.Please help.

Comment: You can get data from existing file and then append your new data in it and save your csv file.

Answer (score 3):

Give this coded a try:

```
<?php
    error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    $data = array();
    $data['name'] = 'test';
    $data['company'] = 'ghgh';
    $data['email'] = 'hgh@ghgh.com';
    $data_row[] = $data;
    $fileName = "example.csv";
    if(!file_exists($fileName)){
        $file = fopen($fileName, 'w') or die("Can't create file");
    } else {
        $file = fopen($fileName,"w");
    }

    foreach ($data_row as $data)
    {
        fputcsv($file,$data);
    }

    fclose($file);

?>
```